# Setting up two throttle rates in one view in django

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, throttling

I am using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7 and now tried to include **throttling** into my webservice. This seemed quite easy at the beginning as Django does all the work for you.
But now I wanted to **only throttle one of my views** *and differentiate between authenticated users and logged in users* aswell as **setting up a 'burst' rate** (e.g. 5 requests per min) **and a 'sustained' rate** (e.g. 100 requests per day).

Achieving this, I built 4 throttle-classes:

```
class SustainedAnon(AnonRateThrottle):
    rate = '100/day'

class BurstAnon(AnonRateThrottle):
    rate = '6/minute'

class SustainedUser(UserRateThrottle):
    rate = '1000/day'


class BurstUser(UserRateThrottle):
    rate = '20/min'
```

I did not change the settings.py at all as it is not needed according to the docs ([Django Throtte Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/)).
The only file I edited was my views.py in which I added this line to my Statistics class

```
class Statistics(APIView):
    throttle_classes = (SustainedAnon, BurstAnon, SustainedUser, BurstUser)
```

It almost does what it is supposed to do. It does only throttle the Statistics class and throttles logged in and anonymous users seperately, **but** it does not throttle the rates correctly.
*When not logged in, the App starts throttling after 3 requests instead of 6 and when logged in after 10 requests instead of 20.*
I guess this is happening because he sets up the cache-request-value in every throttle class that gets called (when not logged in, SustainedAnon and BurstAnon)..
But why is that happening and how can I tell django to only 'throttle once'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#userratethrottle) states:

> An API may have multiple UserRateThrottles in place at the same time.
>   To do so, override UserRateThrottle and set a unique "scope" for each
>   class.

which means you have to configure a different scope for each of the `UserRateThrottle` you are using.

Note that this will also work for `AnonRateThrottle`.

Comment: I already tried that, works fine, but It seems like it is not possible to add TWO scopes to ONE View, so i can't throttle only one view, right?

Comment: of course you can. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#setting-the-throttling-policy tells you how to have specific throttling for one view.